# How should I setup my database with an instable connection?

Tags: mysql, database, raspberry-pi, sensors

In order to log values and work on strategy of a student race car, I am working on a system that logs sensor values and store that into a database. Using a WiFi connection we would like to read these values, but this connection is not very stable. Besides that, we really want to be sure that the computer in the car doesn't have downtime and that it is energy efficient.

Our current design idea consist of a raspberry pi(or beaglebone or equivalent) in the car, and a server in the pits. In the car we would like to log the data, and when we have a connection this should be synchronized to the server in the pits. In the pits there are about 10 laptops that connects to this server where we would like to receive real time data if available, and otherwise the historical data.

MySQL replication looks like the way to go, where the car is the master and the server in the pits the slave. The downside of this is that both computers need to have the same data(correct?). We would like that the car only has the data of today, to have a small database on the raspberry. At the other side, we want a complete archive of racing days on the server in the pits. In the pits we should be able to easily select data from the past 8 days and plot this.

I think we have the following options:

- Complete replication, Synchronize all data from the car to the pitlane. *Easily implementable, but hard for the rasberry and not possible for a lot of data.*
- Replication per day. Replicate the data between the car and the server. On the server we have an archive, *at the end of the day we have to copy the data from replication database to the archive database. This makes it difficult to select data over days.*
- Custom replication. We have to make a script on the pitlane server, that connects to the car and compares that with the database in the pitlane. If there are entries with a newer timestamp it copies it to the archieve. *Custom scripts are less reliable than build in functions. Maybe more intensive for the raspberry, which can result in downtime.*

Is there a better way to do it? That the server in the car automatically clears the database when synchronisation is complete for example, but that auto id's from the rows still keeps counting.

Thank you for thinking with me!
Bart

ps. To give an idea of the data, we have 70 values at 1Hz, 20 values at 5Hz, and 15 values at 20Hz (Double or INT).